# iReport line chart category label

Tags: charts, ireport

i'm using the Line Chart component to generate a chart based on the consumption of a building.
Imagine a possible chart based on the consumption of a building in a period of a month and a resolution of a day. It will have 30 points of consumption corresponding to 30 days. 
The problem is with the category axis labels. With a considerable amount of points, the labels becomes unreadable. How can i just label some points?

My best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a "Line" chart. Instead use a "Time Series" chart.

It automatically handles the issues around charting all points but only labeling a readable number of them. It also handles problems created by data points that are not uniformly spaced.

EDIT: If your incoming data is a String instead of a Date, then you have extra work. Time Series charts expect Times (well, Dates). You'll need to cast your DateString into a real Date. But the work is small, and the benefits are large. Use a variable like this: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse($F{MyDateString})`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that "Time Series" chart requires java.util.Date as the Time period expression and i'm using xml datasource where every data is recognized as string. When it tries to parse the string to a date it throws the corresponding exception.

Comment: Yes, that adds one extra piece. But it shouldn't be too hard to overcome. You just need to cast your String. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to generate a label on the line chart in JASPER report

```
else if(jasperChart.getChartType() == JRChart.CHART_TYPE_LINE) {
    LineAndShapeRenderer line = (LineAndShapeRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
    line.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
    line.setBaseItemLabelGenerator((CategoryItemLabelGenerator) new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
}
```